# Layout not working in Liferay

Tags: templates, layout, liferay

I am using classic theme in Liferay and trying to make a layout. On IDE it is showing completely fine but when I apply it on to my page I don't get the page divided as in the layout.

I can add portlets horizontally line by line but not divided in the layout i created 1-2-2-1.

Below is the code. Please help.

```
<div class="home" id="main-content" role="main">
    #if ($browserSniffer.isIe($request) && $browserSniffer.getMajorVersion($request) < 8)
        <table class="portlet-layout">
        <tr>
            <td class="aui-w100 portlet-column portlet-column-only" id="column-1">
                $processor.processColumn("column-1", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <table class="portlet-layout">
        <tr>
            <td class="aui-w30 portlet-column portlet-column-first" id="column-2">
                $processor.processColumn("column-2", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")
            </td>
            <td class="aui-w70 portlet-column portlet-column-last" id="column-3">
                $processor.processColumn("column-3", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <table class="portlet-layout">
        <tr>
            <td class="aui-w100 portlet-column portlet-column-only" id="column-4">
                $processor.processColumn("column-4", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    #else
        <div class="portlet-layout">
            <div class="aui-w100 portlet-column portlet-column-only" id="column-1">
                $processor.processColumn("column-1", "portlet_56_INSTANCE_F9mSTanO1pkp")
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="portlet-layout">
            <div class="aui-w30 portlet-column portlet-column-first" id="column-2">
                $processor.processColumn("column-2", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")
            </div>

            <div class="aui-w70 portlet-column portlet-column-last" id="column-3">
                $processor.processColumn("column-3", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="portlet-layout">
            <div class="aui-w100 portlet-column portlet-column-only" id="column-4">
                $processor.processColumn("column-4", "portlet_56_INSTANCE_mF6lT48JoIgZ")
            </div>
        </div>
    #end
</div>
```

Comment: How is divided your page when you apply this layout? Which version of Liferay are you using? However this layout doesn't seems a 1-2-2-1 but a 1-2-1.

Comment: my page is divided in horizontal rows only, columns are not at all coming up. Liferay version - 6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liferay 6.2 use bootstrap style layout, so your code was valid up to 6.1. 
Try to change all your `aui-wXXX` with the boostrap class `spanXX`.

For details about boostrap layout see: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

NB

Liferay use bootstrap 2.3.2 and not 3.0

Comment: i know its bit late..but thanks for the info Marco. This worked correctly.
i m very new to this and dont know about the nitigrities. :)